# change default folder for apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, httpd.conf

I have installed a Wordpress instance using Bitnami.

Currently `127.0.0.1` takes my to the file in the `C:\Bitnami\wordpress-4.4.2-1\apache2\htdocs`

I want `127.0.0.1` to take the user to `C:/Bitnami/wordpress-4.4.2-1/apps/wordpress/htdocs`

Changes i have done:
`Edit the httpd.conf file`

```
DocumentRoot "C:/Bitnami/wordpress-4.4.2-1/apps/wordpress/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/Bitnami/wordpress-4.4.2-1/apps/wordpress/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Require all granted
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

`Restarted apache server`

Still going to `127.0.0.1` shows the `index.php` page under `C:\Bitnami\wordpress-4.4.2-1\apache2\htdocs`

What am i missing?

Comment: why do you have the slashes backwards? Under Windows, shouldn't they be  "C:\Bitnami\wordpress-4.4.2-1\apps\wordpress\htdocs"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Windows, but on my Ubuntu system, I also had to change document root in the sites-enabled/000-default.conf file. Just make sure all configuration files are updated correctly to point to your new document root.
Hope this helps!